# Build edk2 in linux

Tags: qemu, uefi, edk2

i'm getting started to write a little and simple application with edk2.

So to write a simple edk2 UEFI application , i have started like this :

#git clone https://github.com/tianocore/edk2.git

```
#. edksetup.sh BaseTools

Loading previous configuration from /media/ledoux/Data/osdev/devos/edk2/edk2/Conf/BuildEnv.sh
WORKSPACE: /media/ledoux/Data/osdev/devos/edk2/edk2
EDK_TOOLS_PATH: /media/ledoux/Data/osdev/devos/edk2/edk2/BaseTools
CONF_PATH: /media/ledoux/Data/osdev/devos/edk2/edk2/Conf

#vi Conf/target.txt
```

(there , i have put :
TARGET_ARCH = IA32 X64
TOOL_CHAIN_TAG = VS2017)

```
# BUILD -a X64

Build environment: Linux-5.7.0-kali1-amd64-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
Build start time: 08:32:11, Sep.03 2020

WORKSPACE        = /media/ledoux/Data/osdev/devos/edk2/edk2
EDK_TOOLS_PATH   = /media/ledoux/Data/osdev/devos/edk2/edk2/BaseTools
CONF_PATH        = /media/ledoux/Data/osdev/devos/edk2/edk2/Conf
PYTHON_COMMAND   = /usr/bin/python3.8


Processing meta-data 
Architecture(s)  = X64
Build target     = DEBUG
Toolchain        = VS2017

Active Platform          = /media/ledoux/Data/osdev/devos/edk2/edk2/EmulatorPkg/EmulatorPkg.dsc
.................. 

- Failed -
Build end time: 08:32:29, Sep.03 2020
Build total time: 00:00:18
```

why the build was failed ??
Is it because the bad repository ??
how can i create OVMF.fd file after build it ???

Answer (score 5):

Here's a complete tutorial for Linux Ubuntu 20. It worked perfectly on my side.

##### Setting up EDK2

Here are the steps I've taken to get EDK2 working **on Linux Ubuntu 20**:

1. `sudo apt-get install build-essential git uuid-dev iasl nasm python python3-distutils python3-apt`
2. `git clone https://github.com/tianocore/edk2.git`
3. Download **brotli** from [here](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/releases/tag/edk2-stable202011) (the third file)
4. Install it in `~/edk2/BaseTools/Source/C/BrotliCompress/brotli`
5. `cd edk2`
6. `make -C BaseTools`
7. Run `. edksetup.sh` (including the dot)
8. Open `Conf/target.txt` in a text editor to change
   **ACTIVE_PLATFORM** to `MdeModulePkg/MdeModulePkg.dsc`
   **TOOL_CHAIN_TAG** to `GCC5` and
   **TARGET_ARCH** to `X64`
9. Download **oniguruma** from [here](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/tree/abfc8ff81df4067f309032467785e06975678f0d)
10. Copy `brotli` to `~/edk2/MdeModulePkg/Library/BrotliCustomDecompressLib/brotli`
    and `oniguruma` to `~/edk2/MdeModulePkg/Universal/RegularExpressionDxe/oniguruma`
11. `build`

If you ever close the bash terminal at any step just rerun `. edksetup.sh` because then you can't run `build` command.

##### Compiling your own efi app

The above will simply show you a bit of how this works in general. Once all this works, you want to compile your own Hello World example like the one below.

```c
#include <Uefi.h>

EFI_STATUS EFIAPI UefiMain (IN EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, IN EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE  *SystemTable){
  SystemTable->ConOut->OutputString(SystemTable->ConOut, L"Hello World\n");
  return EFI_SUCCESS;
}
```

In order to do this, you need to take several more steps.

1. Create a working directory in the edk2 directory like `~edk2/BootloaderPkg`. In there, place 2 files one named `Bootloader.c` and one named `Bootloader.inf`.
2. In `Bootloader.c` place the code above. In `Bootloader.inf` place the following:

```ini
[Defines]
  INF_VERSION                    = 1.25
  BASE_NAME                      = Bootloader
  FILE_GUID                      = 66949615-9653-4a86-8c61-6ef0952973b9
  MODULE_TYPE                    = UEFI_APPLICATION
  VERSION_STRING                 = 1.0
  ENTRY_POINT                    = UefiMain

[Sources]
  Bootloader.c

[Packages]
  MdePkg/MdePkg.dec
  
[LibraryClasses]
  UefiApplicationEntryPoint
  UefiLib
    
[Guids]

[Ppis]

[Protocols]

[FeaturePcd]

[Pcd]
```

3. As stated on https://github.com/tianocore/tianocore.github.io/wiki/Getting-Started-Writing-Simple-Application,

> Update an existing platform .DSC file with your project .inf file. The following list some examples.

So what I did is I took the .DSC file from the MdeModulePackage and I modified it a bit with the following content:

```ini
[Defines]
  PLATFORM_NAME                  = MdeModule
  PLATFORM_GUID                  = 587CE499-6CBE-43cd-94E2-186218569478
  PLATFORM_VERSION               = 0.98
  DSC_SPECIFICATION              = 0x00010005
  OUTPUT_DIRECTORY               = BootloaderPkg/Build
  SUPPORTED_ARCHITECTURES        = IA32|X64|EBC|ARM|AARCH64|RISCV64
  BUILD_TARGETS                  = DEBUG|RELEASE|NOOPT
  SKUID_IDENTIFIER               = DEFAULT

[LibraryClasses]
  #
  # Entry point
  #
  PeiCoreEntryPoint|MdePkg/Library/PeiCoreEntryPoint/PeiCoreEntryPoint.inf
  PeimEntryPoint|MdePkg/Library/PeimEntryPoint/PeimEntryPoint.inf
  DxeCoreEntryPoint|MdePkg/Library/DxeCoreEntryPoint/DxeCoreEntryPoint.inf
  UefiDriverEntryPoint|MdePkg/Library/UefiDriverEntryPoint/UefiDriverEntryPoint.inf
  UefiApplicationEntryPoint|MdePkg/Library/UefiApplicationEntryPoint/UefiApplicationEntryPoint.inf
  #
  # Basic
  #
  BaseLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseLib/BaseLib.inf
  BaseMemoryLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseMemoryLib/BaseMemoryLib.inf
  SynchronizationLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseSynchronizationLib/BaseSynchronizationLib.inf
  PrintLib|MdePkg/Library/BasePrintLib/BasePrintLib.inf
  IoLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseIoLibIntrinsic/BaseIoLibIntrinsic.inf
  PciLib|MdePkg/Library/BasePciLibCf8/BasePciLibCf8.inf
  PciCf8Lib|MdePkg/Library/BasePciCf8Lib/BasePciCf8Lib.inf
  PciSegmentLib|MdePkg/Library/BasePciSegmentLibPci/BasePciSegmentLibPci.inf
  CacheMaintenanceLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseCacheMaintenanceLib/BaseCacheMaintenanceLib.inf
  PeCoffLib|MdePkg/Library/BasePeCoffLib/BasePeCoffLib.inf
  PeCoffGetEntryPointLib|MdePkg/Library/BasePeCoffGetEntryPointLib/BasePeCoffGetEntryPointLib.inf
  SortLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/BaseSortLib/BaseSortLib.inf
  #
  # UEFI & PI
  #
  UefiBootServicesTableLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiBootServicesTableLib/UefiBootServicesTableLib.inf
  UefiRuntimeServicesTableLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiRuntimeServicesTableLib/UefiRuntimeServicesTableLib.inf
  UefiRuntimeLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiRuntimeLib/UefiRuntimeLib.inf
  UefiLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiLib/UefiLib.inf
  UefiHiiServicesLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/UefiHiiServicesLib/UefiHiiServicesLib.inf
  HiiLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/UefiHiiLib/UefiHiiLib.inf
  DevicePathLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiDevicePathLib/UefiDevicePathLib.inf
  UefiDecompressLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseUefiDecompressLib/BaseUefiDecompressLib.inf
  PeiServicesTablePointerLib|MdePkg/Library/PeiServicesTablePointerLib/PeiServicesTablePointerLib.inf
  PeiServicesLib|MdePkg/Library/PeiServicesLib/PeiServicesLib.inf
  DxeServicesLib|MdePkg/Library/DxeServicesLib/DxeServicesLib.inf
  DxeServicesTableLib|MdePkg/Library/DxeServicesTableLib/DxeServicesTableLib.inf
  UefiBootManagerLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/UefiBootManagerLib/UefiBootManagerLib.inf
  VariablePolicyLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/VariablePolicyLib/VariablePolicyLib.inf
  #
  # Generic Modules
  #
  UefiUsbLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiUsbLib/UefiUsbLib.inf
  UefiScsiLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiScsiLib/UefiScsiLib.inf
  SecurityManagementLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/DxeSecurityManagementLib/DxeSecurityManagementLib.inf
  TimerLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseTimerLibNullTemplate/BaseTimerLibNullTemplate.inf
  SerialPortLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseSerialPortLibNull/BaseSerialPortLibNull.inf
  CapsuleLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/DxeCapsuleLibNull/DxeCapsuleLibNull.inf
  PcdLib|MdePkg/Library/BasePcdLibNull/BasePcdLibNull.inf
  CustomizedDisplayLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/CustomizedDisplayLib/CustomizedDisplayLib.inf
  FrameBufferBltLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/FrameBufferBltLib/FrameBufferBltLib.inf
  #
  # Misc
  #
  DebugLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseDebugLibNull/BaseDebugLibNull.inf
  DebugPrintErrorLevelLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseDebugPrintErrorLevelLib/BaseDebugPrintErrorLevelLib.inf
  ReportStatusCodeLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseReportStatusCodeLibNull/BaseReportStatusCodeLibNull.inf
  PeCoffExtraActionLib|MdePkg/Library/BasePeCoffExtraActionLibNull/BasePeCoffExtraActionLibNull.inf
  PerformanceLib|MdePkg/Library/BasePerformanceLibNull/BasePerformanceLibNull.inf
  DebugAgentLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/DebugAgentLibNull/DebugAgentLibNull.inf
  PlatformHookLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/BasePlatformHookLibNull/BasePlatformHookLibNull.inf
  ResetSystemLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/BaseResetSystemLibNull/BaseResetSystemLibNull.inf
  SmbusLib|MdePkg/Library/DxeSmbusLib/DxeSmbusLib.inf
  S3BootScriptLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/PiDxeS3BootScriptLib/DxeS3BootScriptLib.inf
  CpuExceptionHandlerLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/CpuExceptionHandlerLibNull/CpuExceptionHandlerLibNull.inf
  PlatformBootManagerLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/PlatformBootManagerLibNull/PlatformBootManagerLibNull.inf
  PciHostBridgeLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/PciHostBridgeLibNull/PciHostBridgeLibNull.inf
  TpmMeasurementLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/TpmMeasurementLibNull/TpmMeasurementLibNull.inf
  AuthVariableLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/AuthVariableLibNull/AuthVariableLibNull.inf
  VarCheckLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/VarCheckLib/VarCheckLib.inf
  FileExplorerLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/FileExplorerLib/FileExplorerLib.inf
  NonDiscoverableDeviceRegistrationLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/NonDiscoverableDeviceRegistrationLib/NonDiscoverableDeviceRegistrationLib.inf

  FmpAuthenticationLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/FmpAuthenticationLibNull/FmpAuthenticationLibNull.inf
  CapsuleLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/DxeCapsuleLibNull/DxeCapsuleLibNull.inf
  BmpSupportLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/BaseBmpSupportLib/BaseBmpSupportLib.inf
  SafeIntLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseSafeIntLib/BaseSafeIntLib.inf
  DisplayUpdateProgressLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/DisplayUpdateProgressLibGraphics/DisplayUpdateProgressLibGraphics.inf
  VariablePolicyHelperLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/VariablePolicyHelperLib/VariablePolicyHelperLib.inf

[LibraryClasses.EBC.PEIM]
  IoLib|MdePkg/Library/PeiIoLibCpuIo/PeiIoLibCpuIo.inf

[LibraryClasses.common.PEI_CORE]
  HobLib|MdePkg/Library/PeiHobLib/PeiHobLib.inf
  MemoryAllocationLib|MdePkg/Library/PeiMemoryAllocationLib/PeiMemoryAllocationLib.inf

[LibraryClasses.common.PEIM]
  HobLib|MdePkg/Library/PeiHobLib/PeiHobLib.inf
  MemoryAllocationLib|MdePkg/Library/PeiMemoryAllocationLib/PeiMemoryAllocationLib.inf
  ExtractGuidedSectionLib|MdePkg/Library/PeiExtractGuidedSectionLib/PeiExtractGuidedSectionLib.inf
  LockBoxLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/SmmLockBoxLib/SmmLockBoxPeiLib.inf

[LibraryClasses.common.DXE_CORE]
  HobLib|MdePkg/Library/DxeCoreHobLib/DxeCoreHobLib.inf
  MemoryAllocationLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/DxeCoreMemoryAllocationLib/DxeCoreMemoryAllocationLib.inf
  ExtractGuidedSectionLib|MdePkg/Library/DxeExtractGuidedSectionLib/DxeExtractGuidedSectionLib.inf

[LibraryClasses.common.DXE_DRIVER]
  HobLib|MdePkg/Library/DxeHobLib/DxeHobLib.inf
  LockBoxLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/SmmLockBoxLib/SmmLockBoxDxeLib.inf
  MemoryAllocationLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiMemoryAllocationLib/UefiMemoryAllocationLib.inf
  ExtractGuidedSectionLib|MdePkg/Library/DxeExtractGuidedSectionLib/DxeExtractGuidedSectionLib.inf
  CapsuleLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/DxeCapsuleLibFmp/DxeCapsuleLib.inf

[LibraryClasses.common.DXE_RUNTIME_DRIVER]
  HobLib|MdePkg/Library/DxeHobLib/DxeHobLib.inf
  MemoryAllocationLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiMemoryAllocationLib/UefiMemoryAllocationLib.inf
  DebugLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiDebugLibConOut/UefiDebugLibConOut.inf
  LockBoxLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/SmmLockBoxLib/SmmLockBoxDxeLib.inf
  CapsuleLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/DxeCapsuleLibFmp/DxeRuntimeCapsuleLib.inf
  VariablePolicyLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/VariablePolicyLib/VariablePolicyLibRuntimeDxe.inf

[LibraryClasses.common.SMM_CORE]
  HobLib|MdePkg/Library/DxeHobLib/DxeHobLib.inf
  MemoryAllocationLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/PiSmmCoreMemoryAllocationLib/PiSmmCoreMemoryAllocationLib.inf
  SmmServicesTableLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/PiSmmCoreSmmServicesTableLib/PiSmmCoreSmmServicesTableLib.inf
  SmmCorePlatformHookLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/SmmCorePlatformHookLibNull/SmmCorePlatformHookLibNull.inf
  SmmMemLib|MdePkg/Library/SmmMemLib/SmmMemLib.inf

[LibraryClasses.common.DXE_SMM_DRIVER]
  HobLib|MdePkg/Library/DxeHobLib/DxeHobLib.inf
  DebugLib|MdePkg/Library/BaseDebugLibNull/BaseDebugLibNull.inf
  MemoryAllocationLib|MdePkg/Library/SmmMemoryAllocationLib/SmmMemoryAllocationLib.inf
  MmServicesTableLib|MdePkg/Library/MmServicesTableLib/MmServicesTableLib.inf
  SmmServicesTableLib|MdePkg/Library/SmmServicesTableLib/SmmServicesTableLib.inf
  LockBoxLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/SmmLockBoxLib/SmmLockBoxSmmLib.inf
  SmmMemLib|MdePkg/Library/SmmMemLib/SmmMemLib.inf

[LibraryClasses.common.UEFI_DRIVER]
  HobLib|MdePkg/Library/DxeHobLib/DxeHobLib.inf
  MemoryAllocationLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiMemoryAllocationLib/UefiMemoryAllocationLib.inf
  DebugLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiDebugLibConOut/UefiDebugLibConOut.inf
  LockBoxLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/SmmLockBoxLib/SmmLockBoxDxeLib.inf

[LibraryClasses.common.UEFI_APPLICATION]
  HobLib|MdePkg/Library/DxeHobLib/DxeHobLib.inf
  MemoryAllocationLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiMemoryAllocationLib/UefiMemoryAllocationLib.inf
  DebugLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiDebugLibStdErr/UefiDebugLibStdErr.inf
  FileHandleLib|MdePkg/Library/UefiFileHandleLib/UefiFileHandleLib.inf

[LibraryClasses.common.MM_STANDALONE]
  HobLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/BaseHobLibNull/BaseHobLibNull.inf
  MemoryAllocationLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/BaseMemoryAllocationLibNull/BaseMemoryAllocationLibNull.inf
  StandaloneMmDriverEntryPoint|MdePkg/Library/StandaloneMmDriverEntryPoint/StandaloneMmDriverEntryPoint.inf
  MmServicesTableLib|MdePkg/Library/StandaloneMmServicesTableLib/StandaloneMmServicesTableLib.inf
  LockBoxLib|MdeModulePkg/Library/SmmLockBoxLib/SmmLockBoxStandaloneMmLib.inf
  MemLib|StandaloneMmPkg/Library/StandaloneMmMemLib/StandaloneMmMemLib.inf

  NULL|MdePkg/Library/BaseStackCheckLib/BaseStackCheckLib.inf

[Components]
  BootloaderPkg/Bootloader.inf

[BuildOptions]
```

Place that content into a file named `BootloaderPkg.dsc` and place it into your working directory.

4. Change the **ACTIVE_PLATFORM** line in your `Conf/target.txt` file to

```ini
ACTIVE_PLATFORM       = BootloaderPkg/BootloaderPkg.dsc
```

5. Once this is done, you are ready to compile your own EFI application. Open a terminal and type the following commands:

```bash
cd edk2
. edksetup.sh
build
```

Now you should have in the `~/edk2/BootloaderPkg/Build` directory all kind of files including `Bootloader.efi` which is the compiled EFI application.

##### Testing the EFI application

It is nice to have an EFI app now you would like to test it. Write a bash script and type the following commands into it (taken from the [UEFI - OSDev Wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/UEFI#Creating_disk_images)):

```bash
dd if=/dev/zero of=edk2/BootloaderPkg/disk.img bs=512 count=93750
gdisk edk2/BootloaderPkg/disk.img  #o n ef00 w
sudo losetup --offset 1048576 --sizelimit 46934528 /dev/loop7 edk2/BootloaderPkg/disk.img
sudo mkdosfs -F 32 /dev/loop7
sudo mount /dev/loop7 /mnt
sudo cp edk2/BootloaderPkg/Build/DEBUG_GCC5/X64/Bootloader.efi /mnt
sudo umount /mnt
sudo losetup -d /dev/loop7
```

Place that script into your home directory and launch the script. You will be prompted to enter stuff. Type in order <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>n</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>ef00</kbd>, <kbd>w</kbd> and then <kbd>y</kbd>. This will get you to have a `disk.img` partioned with FAT32 and with the file `Bootloader.efi` on it (the EFI app).

Once this is done you need to download OVMF and qemu so type

```bash
sudo apt install ovmf qemu qemu-system-x86
```

Once this is done type the following command to launch the EFI shell in QEMU and test your EFI app.

```bash
sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -cpu qemu64 -drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=0,file=/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd,readonly=on -drive if=pflash,format=raw,unit=1,file=/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_VARS.fd -drive format=raw,file=edk2/BootloaderPkg/disk.img,if=virtio
```

You should see a UEFI shell appear after a few seconds. Then type `fs0:` and then `Bootloader.efi`. This will change directory and then launch your EFI app.

Answer (score 4):

You're building under Linux, so you don't have Visual Studio (which is what VS2017 refers to). The build system really ought to say something more useful about it, but ... I can confirm from own experiments that it doesn't.

Use a toolchain tag of GCC5 instead - that one is still valid for the latest gcc10 builds.

Comment: i'm trying to clone brotli , but some error was occur when compilation ....

Comment: before execute `build -a X64` i should create or make basetools with `make -c BaseTools` , but there i have a lot of error which occur , i don't where where the problem comming from ... stable version of edk2 exist ??

Comment: I recommend you post whatever issues you are having building the BaseTools as a separate question, or in a message to https://edk2.groups.io/g/devel.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised you got as far as you appear to have got with building EDK2.

Here is what I have to do to build it:

- Ensure following packages are installed: gcc-c++, nasm, libuuid-devel, acpica-tools
- Ensure you are using GCC bdf linker, i.e. /usr/bin/ld.bfd, not the gold linker.

As a regular user:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/tianocore/edk2.git
$ cd edk2
$ git submodule update --init
$ cd BaseTools
$ make
```

Assuming you successfully built the tools, next test building an existing EDK2 package:

```
$ cd edk2
$ . ./edksetup.sh
$ build -p MdeModulePkg/MdeModulePkg.dsc -t GCC5 -a X64
...
- Done -
Build end time: 19:36:56, Sep.04 2020
Build total time: 00:02:41
$
```

If the `MdeModulePkg` successfully builds, you are in good shape to build your first UEFI application using EDK2.

Comment: ohh , it is true , i haven't update my repository to take the full version of edk2 , .... thank you very much ...

Comment: but i have don't see `OVMF.fd` in the `build/MdeModule/DEBUG_GCC5`, why ??

Comment: @EsaïeNjongssi.  Did you state that requirement in your question?  You said you wanted to build a "simple edk2 UEFI application."  You never mentioned a port to QEMU.